# The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content

Tags: python, json, django, azure, rest

I'm trying to post to the azure search service using a django post request. I'm getting an issue saying my JSON is invalid, but it passes validation in JSON validators.

This is my function.

```
def uploaddd(request):

    url = 'https://hs.search.windows.net/indexes/hotels/docs/index?api-version=2020-06-30'
    
    data = {
        "value": {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "133",
            "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel",
            "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": ["pool", "air conditioning", "concierge"],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
                "City": "New York",
                "StateProvince": "NY",
                "PostalCode": "10022",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        }
    }
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'key'}

    response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data = data)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

This is the full error

> The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.

Comment: May be you need to use the actual key value instead of the passing string 'key' in the headers section. - Have you masked the key or is it as is ?

Comment: I've masked the key.

Comment: It's a weird one, as the json is valid in validators

Comment: could you try using this
 response = requests.POST( url, headers=headers, data = data)

Comment: I get the following `module 'requests' has no attribute 'POST'. I have imported requests at the top

Comment: oops-my bad ! its in small case  requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data)

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't made a difference, i'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [`REST API documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents#request-body), the `value` element is actually an array. Based on this, can you please try with the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "value": [ 
        {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "133",
            "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel",
            "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": ["pool", "air conditioning", "concierge"],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
                "City": "New York",
                "StateProvince": "NY",
                "PostalCode": "10022",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, please change the following line of code:

```
response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

to

```
response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Here's the complete code I used:

```
import requests, json

url = 'https://account-name.search.windows.net/indexes/hotels/docs/index?api-version=2020-06-30'

data = {
    "value": [{
        "@search.action": "upload",
        "HotelId": "133",
        "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel",
        "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
        "Category": "Boutique",
        "Tags": ["pool", "air conditioning", "concierge"],
        "ParkingIncluded": "false",
        "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
        "Rating": 3.60,
        "Address": {
            "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
            "City": "New York",
            "StateProvince": "NY",
            "PostalCode": "10022",
            "Country": "USA"
        }
    }]
}

print data

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'key'}

response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

print response.text
```

Comment: Despite the json being valid, I'm still getting the following - {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid. Details: parameters : Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.\r\n"}}

Comment: Updated my answer with complete working code. I was able to insert the data successfully.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had to make some alterations, but you helped me big time. Thank you!